# Подставление значений из GET запроса в input. JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, get

Есть HTML форма с фильтрами, после отправки GET запроса или после обновления страницы все значения input'ов слетают. Как с помощью js/jquery вытянуть из адресной строки значения полей и подставиь их обратно в input'ы?

Comment: воспользуйтесь свойствами `Window.sessionStorage` или `Window.localStorage`.

Answer (score 1):

Если очень нужно достать из адресной строки, то можно воспользоваться встроенным объектом для URL адресов, который сам разбирает строку на составляющие.
Алгоритм такой:

1. Берете текущий url из свойства window.location.href
2. На основе url создаете объект URL
3. Он помещает строку с GET параметрами (которые идут после ? в url) в свойство search объекта URl
4. Если такая строка есть, то перебираем коллекцию объекта URL searchParams, которая содержит пары [имя параметра, значение параметра]
5. По имени параметра можно найти соответствующий input и заполнить его
   Простейший пример:

   ```
   function fillInputs(form) {
     let url = new URL(window.location.href);
     if (!url.search) return;
     for (let [name, value] of url.searchParams) {
       form.elements[name].value = value;
     }
   }
   fillInputs(document.forms.myForm);
   ```

Для более сложных случаев (например с радио кнопками) нужно либо дописывать, либо воспользоваться sessionStorage или localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Хочу предложить ещё вариант вытягивания из адресной строки:

```html
<form id=form>
<span id=inputs_txt>
<input type=text name=lastname>
<input type=text name=firstname>
<input type=text name=other>
</span>
<input type=submit>
</form>
<script>
var inputsspan = document.getElementById("inputs_txt");
var inputs_txt = inputsspan.getElementsByTagName("input");
var parametr = location.search.substring(1).split("&");
for(i = 0; i < parametr.length; i ++) inputs_txt[i].value = parametr[i].split("=")[1];
</script>
```

Т. е., инпуты заполняются данными с адресной строки после отправки данных и последующих обновлений страницы. Для реализации этой задачи после обновления без отправки понадобится куки или localstorage.