# При получении параметра из ссылки менять стиль элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Хочу без использования php проверять параметр в ссылке и если параметр есть — менять стиль одного из div.

Для примера ссылка: domain.com/?show=1

```
<h1><span class="hi" style="display:none;">HI</h1>
```

Как можно проверить параметр и если он есть менять на `display:block`?

Comment: что вы называете параметром?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1009734/256824

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался:

```
if (window.location.search.indexOf('show') > -1) {
    jQuery('.success').css({"display":"block"});
}
else {}
```

Comment: else тут не нужен* Можно просто if( ... ) { ... } и всё.